# VueJS's transitions and CSS animations

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-animations

I'm trying to implements a transition between two elements containing **CSS animations** simply by following the [documentation's example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements).

My HTML contains : A button to change my state :

```
<button @click="toggled = !toggled">
  Toggle class ({{ toggled }})
</button>
```

The transition with the two loader (a red and a black one) :

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <div class="loader" v-if="toggled" key="toggled"></div>
  <div class="loader red" v-else key="notToggled"></div>
</transition>
```

It appears that the **VueJS's transition** is waiting for the animation to finish before displaying the next. Am I doing something wrong ?

Reproduce the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/f2vozp35/2/

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry if the post wawsn't explicit enough, I was just trying to achieve what @Stephan-v shown, to have my transition running "smoothly" and not with the delay that you can see in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Explicit-Transition-Durations

Updated fiddle:

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in" :duration="300">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f2vozp35/3/

Vue.js will try to be smart about the transition and will wait for your animation to finish, this way you can explicitly define the duration between the transition.

Comment: Thank, that was it. I though it was due to the animation time of the loaders (since modifying these timers shorten the time of the delay).

Answer (score -2):

Try removing `key` for your divs

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div class="loader" v-if="toggled"></div>
    <div class="loader red" v-else></div>
</transition>
```

Comment: The keys are used by the transition, if I remove them the transition doesn't happen.